# Popover isn't working when attribute is injected after page renders.

Tags: dom, popover, uipopover, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to use popover for certain parts of paragraphs that I'm fetching from my DB and using ng-repeat I load to my html and serve to the front-end.

The relevant part of my DOM, looks like this

```
<div ng-repeat="i in comments" class="ng-scope">
  <div popover="test2" class="task ng-binding"> text1
  <span popover="test" class="highlight-a">text2</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

the ... is injected into the DOM from after some process in the back-end, so the basically the DOM is modified after it loads and renders.
At this point, clicking on the  won't trigger any popovers.
I'm wondering if there's a work-around for re-initiating the popovers or anything like that. Even when I call on to load the popover in the end of the process it doesn't work.